# How to add multiple pages in invoice pdf?

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice-pdf

I am generating an invoice of order. when the order is big means it has a lot of different items in it. It shrinks the text inside the invoice. I want to make it go on two pages or more if the order is big.

These are the template settings given to my template

[image]

Can anyone help me regarding how to add multiple pages or add any option like that there which can allow multiple pages to invoice.

Comment: Means do you want more than one page in pdf of invoice?

Comment: Yes @MayurSisodiya

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the getPdf method in **\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice**

and in the foreach that prints the items you can create a new page:

```
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                //CREATE NEW PAGE
                if ($this->y >= 100 /*YOUR PAGE BOTTOM*/){
                    $page = $this->newPage();
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
```